# PUPPETEER - unable to extract elements on certain websites using page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll())

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to select and `console.log()` the NodeList of all the links of a website in the terminal. However I'm unable to do so accessing certain websites - **google.com**, **facebook.com**, **instagram.com**.

I know that elements are *there*, because I can certainly log them in the actual Chromium console, which loads separately, using `document.querySelectorAll('a')`. But when I'm trying to extract and log links in Node terminal, using

```
const links = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('a'))
console.log(links)
```

I get `undefined`

However, this is not the case for the most websites, for example **yahoo.com**, **linkedin.com**, where my code works. Here it is:

```
const URL = 'https://instagram.com/';
const scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1240,
        height: 680
    });
    await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.waitFor(6000);
    const links = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('a'));
    console.log(links);
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'ig.png'
    });
    await browser.close();
};
```

I tried adding `bypassBotDetectionSystem()` function, as suggested in [this article](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/), but it didn't work. I don't think that that is the issue, because  like I said, I can easily navigate stuff in the Chromium.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to return the `DOM` elements with the `page.evaluate` method, but this is impossible because If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a [non-Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined` as in your case.

You can use the [page.$$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pageselector-1) method instead if you want to get an array of the `ElementHandle`.

Example:

```
const links = await page.$$('a'); // returns <Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>
```

But if you want just get all values of attribute (e.g. `href`) you can take the [page.$$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) method, it runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`

Example:

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', links => links.map(link => link.href));
console.log(hrefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', anchors => [].map.call(anchors, a => a.href));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.