# function in page.evaluate() is not working/being executed - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My Code below tries to collect a bunch of hyper links that come under the class name ".jss2". However, I do not think the function within my page.evaluate() is working. When I run the code, the link_list const doesn't get displayed.

I ran the document.querySelectorAll on the Chrome console and that was perfectly fine - really having a hard time with this.

```
async function testing() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 800});

    await page.goto(url);

    const link_list = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
      let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".jss2"));
      let links = elements.map(element => {
          return element.href;
      });
      return (links);
     });
     console.log(link_list);
}
```

Comment: What's the site, please? Did you try `page.waitForSelector(".jss2")`?

Comment: I am not sure if I can give the website link - however I did try the waitForSelector too. Also, I noticed that the class names of HTML elements on the website on Chromium are different than normally opening the website on chrome. When I click 'Inspect' on chrome the class names are ".jss2" whereas on chromium its ".jss1". I tried my code with ".jss1" and it still does not work.

Comment: @ggorlen Nvm...found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504201/puppeteer-unable-to-extract-elements-on-certain-websites-using-page-evaluate - looks like i had to use page.$$eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const link_list = await page.$$eval('.classname', links => links.map(link => link.href));
```

Found the answer here: [PUPPETEER - unable to extract elements on certain websites using page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504201/puppeteer-unable-to-extract-elements-on-certain-websites-using-page-evaluate)